# is there a way to open a sheet modally at the center in flutter? (not showModalBottomSheet one)

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, panel

I have prepared the following simple illustration to figure out what I want to do;
I know (and already use the showModalBottomSheet) panel in my application. But I would like to use a window (or let's say panel, or sheet or something else which will be a fully form.
Is it possible in Flutter?
[image]
PS: I don't mean alert dialog.

Comment: but why? what you are describing is literally a dialog. for what reason do you not want to use a dialog?

Comment: when I make a sheet (window or screen or sheet...) open, I can open an another one from it, and the other from it. Instead of that, I wanted to a web-like style modal panel that I can switch between them. Yes, surely I can do this with regular (non-modal) screens with a navigation panel, but for particular tasks/purposes that'd work better, I thought. For bottomModalSheet one, I will have to close one to open the other one. am I wrong? This can be a good idea to be used for easy payment steps, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
You can do this with use of `showDialog function`.

use below function, call at `onPressed event of Button`:

```
void openBox(){
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return  SafeArea(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0) ,
              child: Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                  child: Container(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.all(15) ,
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children:[
                            Text("Model Sheet?"),
                            Text("Button, Text, etc."),
                            Text("Full Form"),
                          ]
                      )
                  )
              )
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much dear Pravin. Really appreciated. I just noticed one issue in your code and fixed after a quick workaround. Instead of using openBox() , I revised code to void openBox(BuildContext context) {   showDialog(    context: context,.... to avoid get a dart:js import which returns error, since it's the web-side package. Thanks  again.